# type mismatch when searching for a range

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Search()
'Macro

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Hey guys,

I keep getting a typed mismatch when I look for a range within column "U" 
"It gets stuck on If Cells(x, "U") = MyVars Then" and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Dim copysheet As Worksheet
Dim pastesheet As Worksheet
Dim MyVars As Range
Dim Myline As Range



Set copysheet = Worksheets("RawData")
Set pastesheet = Worksheets("SEARCH")
Set MyVars = copysheet.Range("$Y$1")



pastesheet.Select
pastesheet.Range("$A$12:$Q$5000").ClearContents


'Search According to criteria


Dim x As Long


copysheet.Select

With copysheet.Range("U:U")

For x = 2 To 15000

If Cells(x, "U") = MyVars Then

Cells(x, "A").Resize(, 24).Copy


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    pastesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

        End If

    Next x

End With

pastesheet.Select
Range("$B$6").Select

Beep

MsgBox "Search Complete"


 End Sub
```

Comment: Why use U, and not the column number. I find that way easier. Try going to options > formula's and then select r1c1 reference style so you can directly see the column numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably got an error value somewhere in column U that causing the type mismatch.

Try using this instead:

```
If copysheet.Cells(x, "U").Text = MyVars.Text Then
```

Btw, you've got the `With copysheet.Range("U:U")` ... `End With` lines but you are not actually making use of the `With`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would fix your type mismatch and make your code more efficient. Using With to pre-qualify objects and For Each loops helps over the For x = # to # loop like you used before. Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

```
Sub Search()
'Macro

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim copysheet As Worksheet
Dim pastesheet As Worksheet
Dim MyVars As Range
Dim Myline As Range
Dim MyRange As Range

Set copysheet = Worksheets("RawData")
Set pastesheet = Worksheets("SEARCH")
Set MyVars = copysheet.Range("$Y$1")

pastesheet.Range("$A$12:$Q$5000").ClearContents

'Search According to criteria
With copysheet
    Set MyRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 21), .Cells(15000, 21))
    For Each Myline in MyRange
        If Myline.Value = MyVars Then
            .Range(.Cells(Myline.Row, 1), .Cells(Myline.Row, 24)).Copy pastesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
    Next Myline
End With

pastesheet.Activate
Range("$B$6").Select

Beep

MsgBox "Search Complete"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```